# Logical complex insert into 2 following tables - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a house management project and i am trying to execute a complex function that consists of:
Each time i insert a new Bill into the DB, another table will be filled creating a new row for each share of this bill according to the number of flatmates this house has. I managed to insert into the Bills table but the program returns me to the expected page but with no insert into the Shares table. Not sure if logically i'm doing alright. The code bellow is how i tried to retrieve information of the last insert into the Bills table, which should then have its objects properties used into the Shares table. Does someone have any clue on how i can i proceed?

This is my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $bill = Bill::create($request->all());

        $users = User::where('house_id', Auth::user()->house->id);
        $nflatmates = Auth::user()->house->nflatmates;
        $shared_amount = $bill->bill_amount / $nflatmates;

        foreach($users as $user){

            $data = ['user_id'=>$user->id,
                     'bill_id'=>$bill->id,
                     'share_amount'=>$shared_amount];

            Share::create($data);

        }

        return redirect('/admin/bills');


    }
```

This is my form blade. I believe the problem doesnt come from here. Just in case.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'AdminBillsController@store']) !!}

                            <div class="form-group' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {!! Form::text('description',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Bill Description']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {!! Form::number('bill_amount',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Amount', 'required|between:0,99.99']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="house_id" value="{{Auth::user()->house->id}}">

                            <br>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

These are my relationships:

This is the Share Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\User;
use App\Bill;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Share extends Model{

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'user_id', 'bill_id', 'share_amount', 'share_status'
    ];


    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }

    public function bill(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Bill');
    }


}
```

And this is the Bill Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\House;
use App\User;
use App\Share;

class Bill extends Model{


    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'description', 'bill_amount', 'house_id'
    ];


    public function house(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\House');

    }

    public function share(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Share');
    }



}
```

This is the User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\House;
use App\Role;
use App\Task;
use App\Share;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'is_active','house_id','role_id','password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function house(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\House');

    }

    public function role(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }


    public function task(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');

    }


    public function share(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Share');

    }

}
```

And this is the house Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;
use App\Bill;

class House extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [

        'id','house_address', 'house_admin', 'nflatmates'

    ];


    public function user(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\User');

    }


    public function bill(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Bill');

    }



}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Ive made a possible solution but I've made a guess of your relationships according to your code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The thing is that you obviously have `oneToMany` relationship there, so what you want to do is something like this.</s>

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $bill = Bill::create($request->all());

    $users = User::where('house_id', Auth::user()->house->id);
    $nflatmates = Auth::user()->house->nflatmates;
    $shared_amount = $bill->bill_amount / $nflatmates;

    foreach($users as $user){

        $data = [
           'share_amount' => $shared_amount,
           'share_status' => 'XXXXXX'
        ];

        $share = new Share($data);
        //Associating user with this share
        $share->user()->associate($user);
        //Associating bill with this share
        $share->bill()->associate($bill);
        //Saving share
        $share->save();
    }

    return redirect('/admin/bills');


}
```

**EDIT:**

<s>In order for the code above to work, you must have a valid relationships set across your models.</s>

**EDIT 2:**

I thought that `nflatmates` was a `oneToMany` relationship, but it isn't so there is no need for `attach` function.

We are now creating a `Share` object and through it's relationships that are defined we are using `associate` function based on `Belongs To Relationships` which you can find on [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models), just scroll down a bit.

Comment: Still doesnt work. The error in the laravel.log is the bellow:[2018-02-09 12:55:34] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2445
Stack trace:

Comment: Can you add relationships in your models to your original question? You should probably also include migrations too @LuizWynne

Comment: Jus added the Share and Bill models

Comment: What about these 2 relationships `Auth::user()->house->nflatmates`?

Comment: I added the User and the House Models...does that help?

Comment: Ah I see where I made a mistake, I thought that your `nflatmates` was a relationship and it obviously isn't, let me update the answer @LuizWynne

Comment: Actually, it redirects me as if the function has been completed, and it also insert into the Bills table but not in the Shares table @Nikola Gavric

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164835/discussion-between-nikola-gavric-and-luiz-wynne).